# Inserting a comma after each char in c#

Tags: c#

I need a way to insert a comma after every character in a string. So for example, if i have the string of letters

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

I need to make it so there is a comma after every letter from A, to Z,
I would like to keep the string as it is and not convert it to a char array or something like that. I dont know if thats possible but its just something id like to avoid.

How can i do this?
End result should be this:

```
"A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,"
```

Thanks

Comment: you can avoid an array or a StringBuilder or something similar because strings are readonly. Why avoid then they are friends!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In .Net 4:

```
str = String.Join<char>(",", str) + ",";
```

.Net 4.0 adds a `String.Join` overload that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.
This code calls it with `String` casted to `IEnumerable<char>`.

I need to explicitly specify the generic type parameter or it will call the `params string[]` overload (using a single `string`) instead.

Answer (score 14):

Well you've got to do *something* to generate the new string. The simplest approach would probably be in .NET 4:

```
// string.Join won't put the trailing comma
string result = string.Join(",", (IEnumerable<char>) input) + ",";
```

or

```
string result = string.Join<char>(",", input) + ",";
```

Or in .NET 3.5, where [the overload we want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) doesn't exist:

```
// string.Join won't put the trailing comma
string result = string.Join(",", input.Select(c => c.ToString())
                                      .ToArray()) + ",";
```

If these aren't efficient enough for you, you could always do it manually:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input.Length * 2);
foreach (char c in input)
{
    builder.Append(c);
    builder.Append(',');
}
string result = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: +1, the last method (manual one) does 10000000 times in 3727 ms whereas the `String.Join<char>(",", str)` takes 10543 ms

Answer (score 2):

```
string InsertCommasBetweenChars(string s)
{
    return string.Join(",", s.ToCharArray());
}
```

This `string.Join` overload only exists in .NET 4.0; if you're using an earlier version, you can do that instead:

```
string InsertCommasBetweenChars(string s)
{
    return string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(s.ToCharArray(), c => c.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex replace could work. The regex could be simple as `([A-Z])`, and do a replace with the match plus the , . I would have to lookup how to do it.

See here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx.

```
  Dim input As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  Dim pattern As String = "([A-Z])"
  Dim replacement As String = "$1,"
  Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
  Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop and move char by char then you can append the current char to a `StringBuilder` and add the comma as well.

after the loop is completed you either return the `StringBuilder.ToString()` or assign it to the original string variable if don't need to keep it as it was before as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var input = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var result= String.Join(",", input.ToCharArray(0,input.Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't want char arrays but how's this for a short fix:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", "abc".ToCharArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, grab some [accumulator wisdom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx):

```
var result = "ABCDEFG".Aggregate("", (c, n) => c+ ("," + n)).Substring(1);
```

It 's less readable than .Join but far more flexible.

Comment: `String.Concat(str.Select(c => c + ","))` is much faster.  He _wants_ trailing commas.